# Dockerfile COPY wildcard to only match files, not folders

Tags: docker, dockerfile

In my `Dockerfile`, I want to `COPY` all the files in the root of the context in one go but not the directories. Is this possible with a wildcard, or would I have to list them all?

Comment: did you try to use the .dockerignore? See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

Comment: @user2915097 I don't want to ignore them. They will be copied in a later command

Comment: @Baruch did you work out a solution for this?

Comment: @rannirabadi I don't remember. It has been years since I touched Docker.

Answer (score 0):

That's a tricky one.  Given what you said about not being able to `.dockerignore` the directories, I think I'd probably either:

- list out all the files explicitly, or
- use something to generate the Dockerfile from a template .. this is kind of just a special case of the first option